# cross product of multidimensional arrays

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, cross-product

I have two vectors [image: m1] and [image: m2], each of them has three coordinates [image: ma]  which have sizes 80x80x2000.

I want to calculate the cross product in MATLAB of these two vectors for each time moment. I know that I can extract individually coordinates in nested loops but is it possible to make it avoiding any loops?
here is the sample code with loops

```
m1x = cat(3, [1 2; 3 4], [5 6; 7 8]);

m1y = cat(3, [9 10; 11 12], [13 14; 15 16]);

m1z = cat(3, [17 18; 19 20], [21 22; 23 24]);


m2x = cat(3, [5 6; 2 6], [1 3; 7 9]);

m2y = cat(3, [6 7; 3 5], [2 11; 2 6]);

m2z = cat(3, [3 9; 0 1], [4 2; 3 15]);

result_x(2,2,2)=0; result_y(2,2,2)=0; result_z(2,2,2)=0;

for t=1:2
    for i=1:2
        for j=1:2
            a = [m1x(i,j,t); m1y(i,j,t); m1z(i,j,t);];
            b = [m2x(i,j,t); m2y(i,j,t); m2z(i,j,t);];
            c = cross(a,b);

            result_x(i,j,t) = c(1);
            result_y(i,j,t) = c(2);
            result_z(i,j,t) = c(3);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

so finally I have three components x,y and z of resulting vector for each moment of time

Comment: please give an example with an input toy matrix (2x2x2) and the expected output after cross product.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you want to compute.  Can you please provide a small numerical example?

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you have matrices `A` and `B`, such that each one has t (time) rows and 3 columns (x, y, z) *or if you can reshape them to arrive at this configuration*, you can use:

```
C=cross(A,B);
```

and each row t in `C` will be the cross-product of the corresponding rows in `A` and `B`. Example:

```
>> A=[rand(2000,1),rand(2000,1),rand(2000,1)];
>> B=[rand(2000,1),rand(2000,1),rand(2000,1)];
>> C=cross(A,B);
>> C(1,:)

ans =

    0.0090   -0.0435    0.0756

>> cross(A(1,:),B(1,:))

ans =

    0.0090   -0.0435    0.0756
```